# for loop dictionary not working

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I need to create three dictionaries. I want to use a `for` loop to do this, but it is not turning out the way I want it to. This is my code:

```
names=["lloyd", "alice", "tyler"]

for name in names:
    name = {
        "name": [name],
        "homework": [],
        "quizzes": [], 
        "tests":[],
        }
```

The three dictionaries are being created, but are stored in the variable `name`. I assumed the second `name` (after the line starting the `for` loop) would also be substituted with the values stored in `names`, but this does not happen. How come? How can I fix this?

Comment: `name` is a separate reference one of the strings in the list; setting it to reference another object (like the dictionary) won't change what the list references.

Comment: Why on earth would you assume that? Strings are **not** the same as identifiers, although Python offers various options for converting between them if you do so explicitly. Doing so implicitly would be incredibly frustrating.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, did you actually try and read the first two words of my post? Also, would you mind to go into a little more detail and help me out? I would very much appreciate that.

Comment: So? As a self-confessed *"noob"* you should be even more careful about making assumptions rather than doing research. Why not try following a structured tutorial? This is probably worth a read, too: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names=["lloyd", "alice", "tyler"]

name_dicts = []

for name in names:
    name_dicts.append({
        "name": [name],
        "homework": [],
        "quizzes": [], 
        "tests":[],
        })
```

Now you have an array of dictionaries with all the names.

*Try to avoid using the same variable name for different things* as per @johnsharpe (you should read his link - very helpful)